# swift: SKNode position not animating

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, animatewithduration

I'm rotating a ball based on pan gestures, and I want to add inertia. To do this, I decided to use animateWithDuration when pan gesture finished. The problem is that instead of animating, the position of the ball changes straight away. I'll be posting the code bellow.

```
func moveByInertia(finalPosition: CGPoint, finalRotation: CGFloat)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations:
    {
        self.tommy.position = finalPosition
        self.tommy.zRotation = finalRotation
    })
}
```

The arguments are definitely passed correctly into this function because it moves to the correct position. The problem is that it does so without animating. I couldn't find the same problem with a solution on the internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use Sprite Kit actions, not UIView animations which, if at all, would operate on the entire SKView

Comment: Thank you. I looked them up and used them. If you could just post it in an answer so I can mark it as the best one, and write my solution.